# Windows XP logon script batch file

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, batch-file

How can I write Windows XP logon batch files? Do you have any examples of such files?

Comment: I suppose one would  write a bat file put it in the startup folder and then the command prompt window comes up minimised and runs it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve (change machine/user settings, map network drives, etc. ). Microsoft website has a great number of examples, so do others.

By and large the order of actions goes like this:

1. Create a logon script file.
2. Modify local security policy (Control Panel\Admin Tools\Local Sec Pol) to you the script you just created for either machine or user.
3. Test.

Please be a bit more specific on desired outcome and I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page.](http://superuser.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 0):

As Tavvi said above, it depends on what exaclty you want the batch file to do. They can be used to map a network drive or change user settings. Batch file scripting can range from very simple (list file in a folder, and save to a file) and range to very complex (with menus, user interaction).

For a sample .bat file, open up notepad and type in

> DIR /S > c:\sample.txt.

then save the text file and rename it from ".txt" to ".bat" and run it. This will list all folders in the working directory and save them in a text file on the root of the C:\ drive. You could then put this in a startup folder and it would run when the user logs in.

Bear in mind cmd-line and batch files can be very powerful and can easily cause damage if they are not written and tested properly.